# How to enable CORS and make it work properly with POST in Asp.net Core Web API?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-400

I am trying to create web api using Asp.net Core Web Api and as a front-end i am using React.js.
I have done everything what the official Microsoft Doc says to enable CORS and tried every solution on here but it is not working to POST request. What am i doing wrong here?

I am adding on `ConfigureService` in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddCors();
```

and on `Configure`

```
 app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER")
 .AllowAnyHeader()
 .AllowAnyMethod()
 .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
 .AllowCredentials()
);
```

What is wrong with this code? and on frond-end part I am using fetch() to POST items to the backend, it is working fine to fetch items from backend using GET but not with POST:

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            Ins_Emp: "Ins_Emp",
            Up_Emp: "Up_Emp",
            Item_Code: "Item_Code",
            Item_Name: "Item_Name",
            Item_Spec: "Item_Spec",
            Remark: "Remark",
            Unit_Code: "Unit_Code",
            Up_DateTime: null,
            Ins_DateTime: null,
            Use_YN: null
        }),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-16',
        },
```

I am getting this error from developer tool panel:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elCZd.png)

[image]

Both backend and frontend is being developed on the same laptop on localhost with different port number.

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/elCZd.png shows the problem is that the response is a 400 Bad Request error. It doesn’t show a CORS error. And that 400 error is not caused by your CORS configuration. Instead it’s caused by the request not being formatted in the way the server receiving it expects. So you probably want to check the server logs on the `https://localhost:5001` server to see what messages it’s logging on the server side before it sends that 400 response.

Comment: Hi @Derek, agree with sideshowbarker, you are meeting the 400 bad request error, instead of CORS error. Can you share the related code about the API method? And about the Content-Type property, try to set it to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I will not enable CORS, because you eventually have to disable it in production and that may have unexpected side effects.

Instead, use a proxy during development so that certain URLs (e.g. `/api/*`) are proxied to the server side.

I assume you are using Create React App, please update me if this is not the case.

Solution for CRA: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: Yes i am using Create React App, but enabling proxy also did not help me. the error the same as before.

Comment: have you disabled all CORS-related settings on both the front and back end?

Comment: Yeah, it is working fine without CORS with GET, but when i trie to POST, one thing is changed which is the responce not this one `type:{cors}` but type={basic}

Comment: Did you change all the API URLs to `localhost:3000` instead of pointing directly to your remote web server? After all, your webpage should be sitting together with the back-end at the same host in production right?

Comment: my frontend on `http://localhost:61889/` and my api on `http://localhost:5001/`. and i made `"proxy":"http://localhost:5001"` on package.json. So when i POST and GET from frontend i am just using `fetch("/api/items")`. am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it is not working on POST request. and when enabling proxy if i use https it works fine with GET and give error with POST, and when i use http it is giving HTTP 500 error message, I dont know what is happening

Comment: HTTP 500 is an internal server error. That means your server-side has done something wrong. You are no longer experiencing the CORS issue if you don't see the message in the browser consoile.